# HTML5 video how can i zoom at particular time while playing to particular position and come back to normal automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a video and i need to zoom at particular point (top-left) at particular time suppose exactly at 10 seconds so i need a smooth transition of moving up and coming back to its original position automatically

Answer (score 0):

`video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    // check whether we have passed 5 minutes,
    // current time is given in seconds
    if(this.currentTime >= 10) {
        //do something
     document.getElementById("mainvideo").style.height='400px';
}
});`

> You can try addEventListener and checking current status making changes in dom